# С помощью чего делают зуминг картинок пальцами?

Tags: android

У меня телефон на базе android, там есть галерея картинок, эти картинки можно увеличивать и уменьшать пальцами. С помощью чего это сделано и как это сделано? Это чистая математика или есть методы?

Comment: что именно интересует? как рассчитывают текущий зум? - по расстоянию между пальцами. Или интересует технология тачскрина?

Comment: Технология тачскрина, видимо. Что нужно искать? Что почитать?
Увеличение картинки по кнопке - я поняла.

Comment: тачскрины бывают разными. Две наиболее популярные технологии - резистивные и емкостные. Первые самые простые, но на один клик. Суть - когда нажимаете на экран, он прикасается к подложке, изменяется сопротивление. Его можно измерить и рассчитать положение пальца/стилуса. Емкостные базируются на том, что прикосновение пальцем изменяют емкость и это также можно измерить.

Почитать - гугл быстро находит

 - http://etenclub.ru/board/index.php?autocom=ibwiki&cmd=article&id=256
 - http://chinashops.ru/emkostnoy-resistivniy-touchscreen/
 - http://chinashops.ru/emkostnoy-resistivniy-touchscreen/

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если нужны именно исходники, то посмотрите [вот эту библиотеку](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)