# Увеличение/уменьшение объекта с помощью жестов двух пальцев

Tags: java, android

Как изменять масштаб объекта с помощью жестов пальцами(не помню как это правильно называется. Cropping, или что - то такое, но не суть)

Comment: может zooming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения размера например imageView можно сделать так. Имеется imageView:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Дальше создаем глобальные переменные в `MainActivity` классе:

```
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ImageView mImageView;
```

Следующим этапом мы будем использовать слушатель `onTouchEvent()`:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
return true;
   }
```

Для корректной работы необходимо создать класс `ScaleListener` который будет реализовывать наши действия. Добавлять его следует в классе `MainActivity`:

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector){
mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f,
Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
mImageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
mImageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
return true;
    }
}
```

и вот само использование данного класса на примере `imageView`:

```
mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
```

[Вот](https://medium.com/quick-code/pinch-to-zoom-with-multi-touch-gestures-in-android-d6392e4bf52d) первоисточник который довольно хорошо реализован. Так же есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284610/%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?rq=1) в котором уже поднималась данная тема. В ответе на данный вопрос предложили использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).